# Run an exe file at client sideRegars

Tags: jquery

I have an exe file located at client machine.How can i execute that?

Answer (score 0):

On IE you can do like this but about other borwser this dont work

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
         MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
         function RunNotePad()   
         {  
            MyObject.Run("notepad.exe") ;  
        }  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-IE browsers you can modify the registry to register an application to a URI scheme.

Basically, in the example below for a URI to be called "textEntry" you can modify the registry like so (remember to always back up your registry prior to modifying it!):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  textEntry         
     URL Protocol = ""
     shell
        open
           command
              (Default) = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

Once the registry contains these entries then entering `textEntry:` into the browser should launch Notepad.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/how-start-external-applications-9717.html).